# Visual Studio Express cannot find Intel.dll files but they're in SysWOW64?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I'm compiling a small piece of code for the OpenCV library. I did the tutorial yesterday on http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html along with the Visual Studio stuff and got the tutorial code working, so it cannot be anything related to the library itself.

So I modified the code yesterday a little bit to just do this:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat A = Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64F);
    cout << "A = " << A << endl;
}
```

It compiles correctly but when it debugs, the system says it cannot find and load various PDB files that are IN the folder SysWOW64.

I've attached an image of the errors below. Note that all of those files are in the folder - I did a quick search to check.

Can anyone tell me what to do?[image]

Comment: Title of question is misleading. PDB != DLL

Comment: The missing files are debug symbols, not the DLLs themselves. You are likely not going to debug the Intel files anyway.

Comment: But how can I fix this error? It exits my program regardless of whether or not I use it. @BoPersson

Comment: @developerbmw What is the difference? I'm asking for future reference.

Comment: @Enis - The message *".. has exited with code 0"* means that your program has run to completion and ended without an error code. That's good! If you set a breakpoint in the main function, I'm sure you can single step the two lines and see the result. Also, a .dll file contains code that your program can call, while a .pdb file contains info for the debugger so it can show function names and variables when you debug the .dll. This is important for your own code, but you are likely not going to debug Intel's code, so that some of them are missing is not a big deal.

Comment: @Enis the DLL is the actual library. The PDB (Program Database) is just data used for debugging. You won't need this as you shouldn't need to debug the library.